# DllImport and char*

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I have a method I want to import from a DLL and it has a signature of:

```
BOOL GetDriveLetter(OUT char* DriveLetter)
```

I've tried

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetDriveLetter(byte[] DriveLetter);
```

and

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetDriveLetter(StringBuilder DriveLetter);
```

but neither returned anything in the DriveLetter variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears the function `GetDriveLetter` is expecting a `char*` which points to sufficient memory to contain the drive letter.

I think the easiest way to approach this problem is to pass a raw `IntPtr` and wrap the calls to `GetDriveLetter` in an API which takes care of the resource management and conversion to a `string`.

```
[return:MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetDriveLetter(IntPtr ptr);

public static bool GetDriveLetter(out string drive) {
  drive = null;
  var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);
  try {
    var ret = GetDriveLetter(ptr);
    if ( ret ) {
      drive = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    }
    return ret;
  } finally { 
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Malfist, The value I1 tells the CLR to marshal the value as a 1 byte integer.  It was actually incorrect in this sample as I4 is the correct value (updated a bit ago).  As to why check out this blog entry I wrote on marshalling bool values:  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx

Comment: When I make it I4, I get MarshalDirectiveException

Comment: @Malfist, sorry, it should be `UnmanagedType.Bool`.  Been one of those days.

Answer (score 1):

The StringBuilder is probably the way to go, but you have to set the capacity of the string builder before calling the function.  Since C# has no idea how much memory that `GetDriveLeter` will use, you must make sure the StringBuilder has enough space.  The marshaller will then pass a `char*` allocated to that length to the function and marhsall it back to the StringBuilder.

```
[return:MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern bool GetDriveLetter(StringBuilder DriveLetter);

public static bool GetDriveLetter(out string driverLetter) {
  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(10);
  bool ret = GetDriveLetter(buffer);
  driveLetter = buffer.ToString();
  return ret;
}
```

See the [p/invoke sample for GetWindowText()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html), for an example.

Comment: Doesn't return the correct string, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: What if you add CharSet=CharSet.Ansi to the DllImport attribute?  That is if you care since you have a working solution.

Comment: adding CharSet.Ansi to the DllImport makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern bool GetDriveLetter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]  string DriveLetter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a related situation where the function had a `char *` parameter and I was missing the `CharSet` assignment:

```
[DllImport("library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr MyFunc(string myString);
```