# Marshalling static const char* from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, static, global-variables, marshalling

I have a piece of code and I would like to know if it is correct or not:

hello.cpp

```
static const char _someGlovalVar[] = "my persistant gloval variable";


const char* DLLInterfaceGetName()
{
    return _someGlovalVar;  
}
```

hello.h

```
DLL_EXPORT const char* DLLInterfaceGetName();
```

hello.cs

```
[DllImport("hello.dll", EntryPoint = "DLLInterfaceGetName", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string DLLInterfaceGetName();
```

Is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DllImport and char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568436/dllimport-and-char)

Comment: Looks to be correct, but `id` parameter should be either added to your C++ `DLLInterfaceGetName` declaration and definition or removed from your C# declaration.

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568436/dllimport-and-char. There is another solution how to do it on this link. I would like to now if this solution is correct or not and why.

Answer (score 4):

Change your return value to IntPtr instead of string.

```
[DllImport("hello.dll", EntryPoint = "DLLInterfaceGetName", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr DLLInterfaceGetName();
```

Then when you call it in your C# code, marshall the pointer into a C# string:

```
IntPtr cstr = DLLInterfaceGetName();
String str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(cstr);
```

Also, double check you use the right calling convention on the DLLImport. I had an issue because it uses StdCall by default, and I actually wanted Cdecl.

Comment: Actually, my answer doesn't actually answer your question - it just demonstrates another way to do it.

I did find this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx
There's some info in there about marshaling return values, especially strings. It seems to indicate that the code you have should work behind the scenes the way you would want it to by making a string object and copying the char* into it before handing it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work? In this case, I don't think you have to care about anything else :)

Although personally, I'm a bit worried about how this is handled. A static const char[] pointer is probably in the code section, isn't it? Hopefully, .NET marshaller copies the data in the string to its own string. I'm not sure how the CPP side handles this either - is it possible that different compilers might produce vastly different outputs?

And also, shouldn't you put a `\0` at the end of the string? How does the caller know how long the string is with just `char[]`? I think that if it doesn't work for you, this is the reason.

Comment: Yes, it seems it is working, however I am not sure if it is theoretically correct. There are some access violations in release mode in the library, but I still have not found the reason. I have only a suspicion.