# P/Invoking const char pointer and int reference

Tags: c#, c, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to P/Invoke C function in C# but always getting `System.AccessViolationException`. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

C code:

```
RAYGUIDEF bool GuiListView(Rectangle bounds, const char *text, int *active, int *scrollIndex, bool editMode);
```

C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Rectangle
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float width;
    public float height;

    public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    } 
}

[DllImport(nativeLibName,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern bool GuiListView(Rectangle bounds, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string text,[Out] int active, [Out] int scrollIndex, bool editMode);
```

Comment: I think you cannot use a string equivalent to char* see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568436/dllimport-and-char.  The second problem i see, is that you cant compare the Rectangle struct from the C library with the Managed System.Drawing.Rectangle so you would need to redefine it yourself. Hope this helps...

Comment: @feal, my bad, here is updated version, am using redifined Rectangle scruct.

Comment: what about the string char thing i wrote?

Comment: @feal, i tried [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] attribute and passing raw IntPtr as described in post, but still having that exception((

Answer (score 1):

When passing a pointer with P/Invoke, such as with your `active` and `scrollIndex` variables, you need to use the `ref` keyword in the managed signature. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815276/what-is-the-difference-between-in-out-and-ref-when-using-pinvoke-in-c) for the difference between `ref` and `[out]`.

There are tools available to assist with producing these signatures. Using P\Invoke Interop Assistant:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("<Unknown>", EntryPoint="GuiListView")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern  bool GuiListView(Rectangle bounds, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text, ref int active, ref int scrollIndex, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)] bool editMode) ;
```